# Button directly under first text of left column in a 2-columns grid

Tags: css, css-grid

How could I place the button directly under the first paragraph on the first column? I know it's caused by the second paragraph being longer but I'd like to avoid the gap.

As I'd like to have the button last on mobile (all stacked), I'm not I can really move it in the HTML.

```css
.text {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "a b" "c b";
    /* grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content); this doesn't work either */
    column-gap: 24px;
}
p:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-area: "a";
}
p:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-area: "b";
}
.button {
    grid-area: "c";
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro mollitia. Tenetur quibusdam at voluptate aut expedita!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, est asperiores maxime id architecto libero commodi, corrupti sit iusto deserunt quos! Ipsa inventore soluta laudantium repellat culpa! Incidunt, quam eos.</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

What I get now:
[image]
What I'd like instead:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a [Mobile First](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) design approach:

```css
.text {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a" "b" "c";
  column-gap: 24px;
}

p:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: a;
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: b;
}

.button {
  grid-area: c;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
}


/* For non-mobile: */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .text {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "a b" "c b";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, porro mollitia. Tenetur quibusdam at voluptate aut expedita!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum, est asperiores maxime id architecto libero commodi, corrupti sit iusto deserunt quos! Ipsa inventore soluta laudantium repellat culpa! Incidunt, quam eos.</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

[image: Video screen shot recording showing mobile vs desktop]

<sup>*Note*: Change the width as needed. I set it to `500px` specifically for this example as a SO snippet.</sup>

Comment: This is so perfect! Always a bit confused with `grid-template-areas` but it's so powerful. Thank you.